# Can I override RESTClient default "HttpResponseException" response to >399 Return Codes?

Tags: testing, groovy, spock, rest-client

I'm using the Groovy [RESTClient](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/RESTClient.html) class to do write some (spock) Acceptance tests for Java WebServices I've been authoring.

One frustration I've had is in testing the responses...

`200` Status's are easy:

```
when:  def result = callServiceWithValidParams()
then:  result.status == 200
```

But with `400+` I'm forced to either wrap in a `try-catch`, or test for the `HttpResponseException` that `RESTClient` throws by default.

```
when:
    callWithInvalidParams()
then:
    def e = thrown(Exception)
    e.message == 'Bad Request'
```

This is sort-of OK, if a little frustrating... but I want to do better.

Ideally, I want my tests to more resemble this 
(*might be confusing if you don't use groovy/spock*)

```
@Unroll
def "should return #statusCode '#status' Response"()
{
    when:
    def result = restClient.get(path: PATH, query: [param: parameter])

    then:
    result.status == statusCode

    where:
    status         | statusCode | parameter                
    'OK'           | 200        | validParam
    'Bad Request'  | 400        | invalidParam
}
```

In the above example, the 'Bad Request' case fails. Instead of returning a value, `restClient.get()` throws `HttpResponseException`

Comment: It's hard to understand the barrier your facing. Can you post more info? What type is params? What happens when you try to use the where block to define params? What does callService() look like?

Comment: @AlexBlakemore thanks for the response. The example at the end is just meant to illustrate how my original request might help me. I see now that its somewhat confusing, as I don't actually show the RESTClient. Think of `callService(params)` as a wrapper around the client where the `params` values are maps of queryString params to be sent to the service. All of this is not really important though. The main point is that the RESTService returns a `result` for 200 responses, but throws an error for 400, 401, etc... so I cannot test the response in a standard way in my `then:` block

Comment: Just editted the example to hopefully make more simple/clear.

Comment: Then why not make a convenience method that wraps your REST calls that catches exceptions and turns them into status codes?

Comment: I guess I could do that, but it will get a bit sloppy. For one, I'll have to create a way to map the error names (like 'Bad Request', 'Unauthorized'...) to the corresponding code (400, 401...) which aren't present in the HttpResponseException. When it comes down to it, that approach would be OK (and maybe merits an answer if you want some internet points), but I'm just hoping there may be a more elegant way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Tomasz already linked in a comment, here is my little one-liner [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29883754/1073826) from a similar question.

```
client.handler.failure = client.handler.success
```

Answer (score 17):

@JonPeterson came up with what I think is a better solution, so I gave [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31761860/363701) the checkmark:

```
client.handler.failure = client.handler.success
```

[*More info here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966548/groovy-httpbuilder-get-body-of-failed-response/29883754#29883754)

---

**The solution I (previously) landed on:**

```
 restClient.handler.failure = { it }
```

Which is shorthand for

```
restClient.handler.failure = { resp -> return resp }
```

---

*@JimmyLuong* noted in the comments that this approach drops the data from the response, and suggested the following enhancement:

```
 restClient.handler.failure = { resp, data -> resp.setData(data); return resp }
```

Comment: Using this solution for me worked well, except for the data being dropped from the response. To get the data, I had to do something like: restClient.handler.failure = { resp, data -> resp.setData(data); return resp }

Comment: The approach suggested by @TomaszKalkosiński is even simpler and works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to make a Groovy convenience method that wraps your REST calls that catches exceptions and turns them into status codes